# Override default npm install from InitelliJ IDEA

Tags: npm, intellij-idea, npm-install, jetbrains-ide

Is there a way to override the default npm install script proposed by IntelliJ, I mean the one that appear as a notification when your package.json change or the one from the context menu when you right click the package.json.

I would like to add an option such as "--legacy-peer-deps".

Or do I have to run it through the terminal every time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this command can't be customized, so you have to either run the command in terminal or create the corresponding [npm run configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-npm.html):

[image]

Comment: Oh I see, thanks for the confirmation.
I will keep doing what I was doing then.